# preserving whitespace with svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to draw text with SVG.JS and preserve whitespace

```
var draw = SVG('drawing')
var text = draw.text("040: .P .E       .L 01                         ")
```

just prints:

```
040: .P .E .L 01
```

I was suggested

```
this.el.lines.each(function() {
      this.exportAttr({
        'xml:space': 'preserve'
      })
    })
```

but this doesn't seem to work, as https://raw.github.com/wout/svg.js/master/dist/svg.js doesn't contain `exportAttr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see my suggestion was wrong because it targets the export plugin.
It should be this of course:

```
var text = draw.text(' with     a lot of    white t e    s p a c e')
text.lines.attr('xml:space', 'preserve', 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace')
```

Comment: doesn't work ? <html>
<body>
<div id="svg"></div>
<script src=svg.js></script>
<script>
draw = SVG('svg')
text = draw.text(' with       white   space ') // your text
text.lines.attr('xml:space', 'preserve')
</script>
</body>
</html>

gives
"with white space"

Comment: I updated my example. When in the html DOM you should provide the namespace as well. Visible in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/wout/fg77n/

Comment: thanks - is there a way to set this by default for all text attributes?

Comment: No, not yet. But the next release will have some kind of function to enable whitespace preservation on text elements so that all generated content will have this attribute applied by default.

Comment: This is apparently deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xml:space